# Facebook Like Box Is not Showing

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-likebox

I created a website for my project in programming class (It isn't published and it uses url's in my pc)

I'm having a problem making the Facebook like box appear in my webpage

Here's a screenshot of what my page look's like ( I am connected to the internet and currently logged in my facebook account)

I used the iframe version of the code

http://i784.photobucket.com/albums/yy129/jian_lastino2000/qwert.jpg (sorry i'm in a rush...the system says that I need 10 reputation to post images xD)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/general/favicon.png" width="32px" height="32px" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>RCICT 2012</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="yes" />
    <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
    <meta name="Project1" content="project 1 for lbyec71" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="programming html" />
    <meta name="Jian Lastino" content="RCICT 2012" />
    <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/master.css";</style>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">function nav(){
$('div#nav ul li').mouseover(function() {
$(this).find('ul:first').show();
});

$('div#nav ul li').mouseleave(function() {
$('div#nav ul li ul').hide();
});

$('div#nav ul li ul').mouseleave(function() {
$('div#nav ul li ul').hide();;
});
};

$(document).ready(function() {
nav();
});</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</head>
<body class="about">
<div id="page-container">
<div id="menu">

        <table border="0" style="border-spacing: 85px 0px;"> 
<tr>
<td> 
<a href="mypage.html"  "text-decoration:none" ;>
Home</a>
</td>
<td> 
<a href="committees.html"  >
Committees</a>
</td> 
<td> 
<a href="tracks.html">Conference Tracks</a> 
</td> 
<td> 
<a href="dates.html">Important Dates</a>
</td> 
<td> 
<a href="submission.html">
Abstract Submission Procedure</a>
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div></br></br>

    <div id="header">
    <object width="900" height="150"
classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0">
<param name="SRC" value="header.swf">
<embed src="header.swf" width="900" height="150"></embed>
</object>
</div>
    <div id="sidebar-a">
    <div class="padding">
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Frcict2012&amp;width=292&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;appId=165351403548315" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="content" >
    <div class="padding">
    <h2><img src="images/headings/about.png" alt="About" /></h2></br>

    <p><strong>The 5th Regional Conference on Information and Communication Technology  (RCICT 2012) is the fifth AUN/SEED-Net Regional Conference in ICT fields that will be held on October 18-19, 2012 in Traders Hotel,Manila,Philippines. The RCICT is a discussion of ideas, techniques, and innovations in the field of advanced computing among scientists, engineers, and practitioners. We encourage the submission of works in progress. We will provide a friendly environment where researchers can discuss current and future trends in their research areas.</strong></p>
    <strong><p>In addition, the 1st National Conference of Computer Engineers of the Philippines will be also held in conjunction with the said event.</p></strong>

    <h2><img src="images/headings/contactperson.png" alt="Contact Person" /></h2>
    <h3>Engr. Cesar A. Llorente</h3>
    <p>
CPE/ECE Department, De La Salle University-Manila, Philippines.</br>
Phone: +632 524-4611 Local 224</br>
<a href="mailto:cesar.llorente@dlsu.edu.phSubject=Hello%20again">Send E-mail</a></br>
</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="footer">
    <div id="altnav">

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rcict2012" target="_blank";><img src="images/footer/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/rcict2012" target="_blank";><img src="images/footer/twitter.png" alt="Facebook" /></a> 
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a> - 
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>

    </div>
    <div id="copyright">
    |<a href="mypage.html">Home</a>|<a href="committees.html">Committees</a>|<a href="tracks.htnk">Conference Tracks</a>        |<a href="dates.html">Important Dates</a>|<a href="submit.html">Abstract Submission Procedure</a>|</br>
    Potato &copy;<br />
    Designed By <a href="http:/facebook.com/jlastino" target="_blank">Jian Lastino</a> and <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dampoy.orsolino" target="_blank"> Dampoy Orsolino</a>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please post your code ,so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

By using iFrame is correct. I think your code is also correct. But you have to use local server as LAMP or Xamp. It will run...